# Static IP for a VM

Tags: networking, router, virtualbox, ip, bridge

I've an existing network with multiple components. DHCP server is setup on router with range 192.168.0.11-254/24, addresses below are static IPs set on the devices directly. The setup works great so far.

Now, I would like migrate one of my hardwares (RPI) to a VM on a different server (192.168.0.8). The issue is with the networking, before the migration I've used static IP for the RPI (192.168.0.3) and all clients (IoT) have hardcoded IP address, so I would like to keep it. Also server IP address important too, as it already host some services which are port-forwarded to WAN.

How should setup networking on host server (192.168.0.8) to get my request routed from 192.168.0.3 to a specific VM?

The router is Asus RT-AC88U with Merlin firmware so it has plenty options...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

NAT Networking uses the VM App internal DCHP server and it is impractical to use a Static IP in a NAT situation.

However, you can change the networking to Bridged networking and then it is entirely practical to assign your VM a static IP on the router.

You set up the type of networking (Bridged or NAT) in the Guest machine.

In your situation described in your question, Bridged networking is the solution for you.

To set up Bridged Networking in Virtual Box, see this Oracle Guide.

[Oracle VBOX Bridged Networking](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/network_bridged.html#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20bridged%20networking%2C%20open,network%20interfaces%20of%20your%20systems.)

> To enable bridged networking, open the Settings dialog of a virtual
> machine, go to the Network page and select Bridged Network in the
> drop-down list for the Attached To field. Select a host interface from
> the list at the bottom of the page, which contains the physical
> network interfaces of your systems.

Comment: Thanks, can you please improve your answer with a step by step guide how to setup bridge? Should I do it in Ubuntu or using `virsh` command?

Comment: Done. My post should do it for you, but you can also refer to the Oracle article.

Comment: For clarity for you, Network Type is set up in the Guest Machine .